# iPhone style guidelines

Tags: iphone, xamarin, monodevelop, styling

I'm looking for some well known style guidelines for mobile applications.

My application is primarily forms based using Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "Safari and WebKit Development for iPhone OS 3.0" is a little older but have nice tips about it. [Like this one](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/best-practices-iphone-ui-design).

I will although encourage you to use some kind of template first [like this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-design-tutorials/iphone-design-templates/).

But I'm sure the best place is the [iOS human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html), directly from the Apple team.